# Table and Sum function in Mathematica

Tags: sum, wolfram-mathematica, overlap

I have a very simple question. I don't use Mathematica very often and I got stuck with one task. I need to compute this task:

```
T=5;
y (* it represents 54 numbers*);  
h = 2;
c (*starting at 3, see below*);   



Table[Sum[(y[[i]]*((i - c)/h)*((i - c)/h)), {i, T}]/
      Sum[((i - c)/h)*((i - c)/h), {i, T}], {c, 3, 54, 2}]
```

I need to compute the "sum…/sum…" 26 times, where "c" starts at 3 and in another step it is (3+2)-> 5 and so on (e.g. 2 steps). I managed to implement this task with Table function.

The problem is, that I also need the "i" to go from 1 to 54, but in one step it should compute just 5 numbers: 1st computing i=1,2,3,4,5 ; 2nd computing i=3,4,5,6,7 and so on. In the sum function I implemented T as 5, so in first step everything is ok, but I have no idea how to create the loop where "i" overlaps like that. I hope that someone will understand my "great" explanation.

Comment: You could simply make your `T` a function of `c` returning the list of `i`s you need, e.g. `T[c=3] = {1,2,3,4,5}`, `T[c=5] = {3,4,5,6,7}`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I wrote T[c=3]={1,2,3,4,5} this emerged:     Set::write: Tag Integer in 5[3] is Protected. >>

Comment: It was not meant literally,  sorry if I confused you.
What are values for `i` for a generic value of `c` ?

Comment: I have already used the other answer, but thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write `T` as `c+2`, but your table is too long, i.e.

```
z = Table[c, {c, 3, 54, 2}]
```

> {3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53}

```
z + 2
```

> {5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55}

So again, if you wrote `T` as `c+2`, (and minimum `i` as `c-2`) . . .

```
Table[Sum[(y[[i]]*((i - c)/h)*((i - c)/h)), {i, c - 2, c + 2}]/
  Sum[((i - c)/h)*((i - c)/h), {i, c - 2, c + 2}], {c, 3, 54, 2}]
```

. . . you would need `y` to represent a list of 55 numbers, not 54.

For example, this works ok :-

```
y = Array[RandomInteger[10] &, 55];

Table[Sum[(y[[i]]*((i - c)/h)*((i - c)/h)), {i, c - 2, c + 2}]/
  Sum[((i - c)/h)*((i - c)/h), {i, c - 2, c + 2}], {c, 3, 54, 2}]
```